# each() function returning Null or Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I am newbie in programming and I am trying to learn and make it work with each(). Bear with me. I try my best to learn from here and you.

1. I am trying to go through the item per product in a catalog for the specific prices: either original and sale from the page.
2. then calculate the % for discount
3. print discount %
4. check to compare the percent to color the background: brown, yellow and red.

Now, I test each line to see if it works or not. 
`salecost = $(this).find('#sale').html();` returns a few nulls before displays amount with dollar signs. Weird couldn't figure that one out. Replace() isn't working right - couldn't get it working. It is supposed to remove dollar sign.

Also, I am not sure how it goes with compare -- do i write statement correctly?

Thank you in advance for the help

```
var salecost;
var originalcost;
var percentDiscount;
var percent; 

function calculate(sale, original)
 {
  percentDiscount = eval((sale/original)*100);
        document.getElementById("percentoff").innerHTML=parseInt(percentDiscount) + '%';       
 }

$(document).ready(function(index){

           $('.item').each(function(){     
            salecost = $(this).find('#sale').html();
            salecost = salecost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,"");
            alert (salecost);
             originalcost = $('#sale').html();
             originalcost = originalcost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,"");
             alert (originalcost);
             percent = calculate(salecost,originalcost);
             alert(percent);

               if(percent<30)
               {
                       $("div#percentoff").css({"background-color":"brown", "padding":"5px 0"});
               }

               if(percent<50){
                       $("div#percentoff").css({"background-color":"yellow", "padding":"5px 0"});
               }

               if(percent<70){
                       $("div#percentoff").css({"background-color":"red", "padding":"5px 0"});
               }
       });
});
```

Comment: You have more than one item with same ID. It's wrong. Give unique ID to each element and use class instead, e.g. <div class="sale"> and then: $(this).find('.sale').html() should work fine.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code also?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is a good place to post the code so we can see it in action

Comment: cool never heard of jsfiddle. thanks.

Comment: @Shadow_Wizard @generalhenry @rahul - Thanks to you all. I got it working as you can see http://www.jsfiddle.net/dreamlex/bceu3/14/. but when i copied and pasted the code onto files in local dev. it is not working anymore so I went to error console on firefox - it says salecost is null. I am not sure what could cause that null for salecost? Any insight will be appreciated. thank you

Comment: @Shadow_Wizard @generalhenry @rahul http://www.jsfiddle.net/dreamlex/bceu3/15/ -- i tested it on local development with alert msg and i see that salecost is null for "salecost = $(this).find('.price').html();" so how to resolve null thing?

Comment: @Josephine: too much mess here, edit your original post, add the code you currently use and explain better what exactly is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should move your var statements to within the each function so they're not global.
2. You don't need to you the eval, (sale/original)*100 will work by it self.
3. It's better to use consistent style, your calculate function could be written using jquery.

   $("#percentoff").html(percentDiscount) + '%');
4. casting is unnecessary for most cases in javascript, concatenating a number with a string will produce a string.
5. your calculate function should `return percentDiscount;`
6. Instead of using .css() it would be better to use .addClass that way it's easy to undo with .removeClass, the style is all the the style sheet and you can use jquery to select the elements with the class.

Comment: only thing the sale and original prices are string, so don't we need eval()?

Comment: when I tested the script, alert message shows 1159987460 which doesn't exist anywhere on the product page. 319 from the first product is also applied to the remaining products on the same html code just that repeats the item per product. I am not sure why it happens. Any insight on this?

Comment: the cast from string to number is implied by the / operator, if you want to be more formal you can use Number(sale)/Number(original)

Comment: suggestions* --> tested and i am still stuck with "missing ; before statement - $("#percentoff").html(percentDiscount) + '%'); \n" when there is a comma. Any insight on this one?

Answer (score 2):

This is not required

```
$(this).find('#sale').html();
```

You can replace this using

```
$("#sale").html();
```

since id will be unique in a document. If you have more than one element with the same id then your HTML is invalid.

***Edit***

Remove the id from the span tag.

```
<span class="price">S$319</span>
```

This will find all the spans[here only 1] with class name `price` inside the parent div. No need to use `.html()` here, you can use `.text()`

```
$(this).find('span.price').text();
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the fast reply. I have tried $("#sale").html() but it only shows one price per product but apply it to other product as well. So how to go around it?

Comment: You can use a class name for this.

Comment: it would help if we could see some of the html.  Ids are unique so it sounds like the `#sale` should be a `.sale` instead.

Comment: hi thanks generalhenry. i copied html. i am using cart software.

Comment: <div class="item">
    
   
    <a href="http://localhost:8888/">
    <img src="images/hpa100060.jpg"  alt="Holiday Purse" title="Holiday Purse"/>
 </a>

    <div class="description">
    <div class="percentholder"><span id="original" class="actualprice"><s style="color: #736357;">S$460</s></span>&nbsp;<span id="sale" class="price">S$319</span>   
<div id="percentoff" style="padding:5px 0;"></div></div>      
                
     <p><a href="http://localhost:8888/>Holiday Purse</a></p>
<p><span class="designer">by <a class="link" href="http://localhost:8888/">Designer</a></span></p>

Comment: looks like you should replace #sale with .price and use .actualprice to find the original price

Comment: one more question-salecost is null, says on error console, what does it mean?

Comment: I have already replace #sale with .price and .actualprice.. but I am stuck at the "salecost is null" error.

Comment: salecost = $(this).find('.actualprice').html();
            salecost = salecost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,"");

Comment: is it correct? because it gives alert error "salecost is null"

Comment: @Josephine edit your original post and explain there what you have done and what error you now get. To get attention of someone in comment use @NameHere for example @Shadow should "ping" me. Without it people won't see the comments you are adding unless browsing directly to the question, or adding it to their favorites..

Comment: @Shadow got it. I have already figured it out except conditions

Comment: @Shadow_Wizard @generalhenry @rahul jsfiddle.net/dreamlex/bceu3/15 -- i tested it on local development with alert msg and i see that salecost is null for "salecost = $(this).find('.price').html();" so how to resolve null thing?

Comment: @Shadow_Wizard @generalhenry @rahul - not only salecost being null but other function for price range isn't working anymore. how come?